# Unable to resolve unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to submit some data from the frontend into my backend but I'm coming up across this error:

```
(node:5472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)
(node:5472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the 
CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 10)
```

I believe that this is where the error is happening so I tried adding a catch block but I still keep getting the same error and I'm not sure why. My code is below:

```
const FeedbackRepository = require("../repositories/feedback");
const TagRepository = require("../repositories/tag");
const MoodRepository = require("../repositories/mood");
const FeedbackTransformer = require("../transformers/feedback");

class FeedbackService {
    constructor() {
        this.repository = new FeedbackRepository();
        this.moodRepository = new MoodRepository();
        this.tagRepository = new TagRepository();
    }

    saveFeedback(feedbackRequest) {
        let feedback = FeedbackTransformer.requestToModel(feedbackRequest);

        return this.repository.saveFeedback(feedback).then(id => {
            return Promise.all([this.moodRepository.saveMoods(feedback.moods.map(m => { 
                                    m.feedbackId = id;
                                    return m;
                                })),
                                this.tagRepository.saveTags(feedback.tags.map(f => { 
                                    f.feedbackId = id;
                                    return f; 
                                }))])
                    .then(results => ({ id }))
                    .catch(function () {
                        console.log("Promise rejected")
                    });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = FeedbackService;
```

Comment: Try adding the `.catch(…)` after the *outer* `.then(…)`. Currently you're not catching errors from `this.repository.saveFeedback` but only from the promises in `Promise.all`